# How to display hidden functions in menu bar?

Tags: interface

I use (and study) the Blender 2.8x and find the Solidify function in menu of Mesh in Edit mode by hotkey F3 and entered keyword but the function don't displayed in menu bar. How display all available and hidden functions in menu bar? How to get a list of all hidden functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function is available in *Edit mode* under *Face > Solidify Faces*.
You can then adjust it in the pop-up overlay.

I believe all functions are accessible through the main menu bar, they're just hard to find sometimes. :).

[image]

Comment: Hmm... I a lot times tried find it in all submenu but don't find it. Amazing ;) Thanks!

Comment: You're right. I was sure it was in there, but it still took me a few minutes :)